# Storage of data in generated in a multidimensional structure

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, structure

I am running code generated by three nested loops and need to store the results of 14 variables for each combination of the three loop index variables i, j, and k.  What do you recommend as the best array or structure to store these for easy access to plotting?  Two of the 14 variables are character (string) variables.

I know I could make a multidimensional array for storing most of my variables, but that lacks variable names that could be connected with the data.  Something like
    s1.MSE = MSE
except this is scalar. I don't know how to successfully make this three-dimensional.  I thought it would be something like 
    s1(i,j,k).MSE = MSE 
but this has not worked.

I do not quite understand the response regarding the creation of a class that contains all 14 of my variables.  I will do more research into that possibility.
Thanks to those who responded.

Comment: Go ahead and provide sample data, or a sample of your code that's relevant to your question!

Answer (score 0):

Make a class of those 14 variables and make a 3d vector/array of that class and store your results in that vector.